# TinyMCE not appearing in Flask

Tags: python, flask, tinymce, flask-wtforms

I've followed this guide quite closely: https://www.kevin7.net/post_detail/2 but can't seem to get TinyMCE to work in my Flask application.

Essentially it doesn't render on the screen at all, as if I'm missing something.

This is the code I'm using in the html template. I'm trying to get it to render the content text area field from the create post form.

```
  <h1> TEST </h1>
  <script type="textarea/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="textarea/javascript">
      tinymce.init({
      selector: '#content',
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink link image imagetools lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
        'save table contextmenu directionality template paste textcolor codesample'
      ],
      toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample',
      codesample_languages: [
        {text: 'HTML/XML', value: 'markup'},
        {text: 'JavaScript', value: 'javascript'},
        {text: 'CSS', value: 'css'},
        {text: 'Processing', value: 'processing'},
        {text: 'Python', value: 'python'}
      ]
      });
  </script>
```

Below is the PostForm I'm trying to attach it to. The content field.

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the author of that article which incidentally url has changed to

```
https://www.kevin7.net/post_detail/tinymce-and-flask
```

I notice you have a typo in your code..

You have:

```
script type="textarea/javascript"
```

But it should be

```
script type="text/javascript"
```

Besides that everything looks fine. I copied your code onto my PC and it works.

Also I assume you are passing the form to your template? I left that out in the original blog posting, I will try and update the blog to include all the details soon.

Answer (score 0):

I spend quite time to solve similar problem which i also referenced from exact that website. I needed to add some additional code to make it work for my flask application. I will post here maybe someone can find it helpfull.

First i needed to add below code inside tinymce.init:

```
        setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('change', function (e) {
        editor.save();
    });
```

And this allowed me to post edited content but rendering was still problem. To solve that i needed add |safe into my jinja template like below:

```
    {% for post in posts.items %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/' + post.author.image_file) }}" alt="">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="{{url_for('user_posts', username=post.author.username)}}">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{url_for('post', post_id=post.id)}}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|safe }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

You see that there is "|safe" just after my content. And know i can render everything i edit with tinymce.